# This in a default method in interface

Tags: java, functional-programming, this

In my understanding the way lambdas work is similar to creating instance of an anonymous class and providing the implementation of an abstract method - please feel free to comment on this

I have also been looking into combinator pattern in Java and getting confused by "this" in the and method of the below interface, in my understanding, `this` refers to a current instance of a class. When I am doing `System.out.println(this)` in the `and` method, it prints `combinatorpatttern.CustomerRegistrationValidator$$Lambda$4/0x0000000800067440@12f40c25`, which is not making sense as to what class this is referring to.

```
public interface CustomerRegistrationValidator
        extends Function<Customer, ValidationResult> {
  
   static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
        return customer -> {
            System.out.println("running email validation");
            return customer.getEmail().contains("@") ?
                    SUCCESS : EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
        };
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isPhoneNumberValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getPhoneNumber().startsWith("+0") ?
                SUCCESS : PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID;
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isAnAdult() {
        return customer ->
                Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ?
                        SUCCESS : IS_NOT_AN_ADULT;
    }
    
    default CustomerRegistrationValidator and (CustomerRegistrationValidator other) {
        return customer -> {
            
            ValidationResult result = this.apply(customer);
            return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
        };
    }

    enum ValidationResult {
        SUCCESS,
        PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID,
        EMAIL_NOT_VALID,
        IS_NOT_AN_ADULT
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(
                "Alice",
                "alice@gmail.com",
                "+0898787879878",
                LocalDate.of(2015, 1,1)
        );
        
        ValidationResult result = isEmailValid()
                .and(isPhoneNumberValid())
                .and(isAnAdult())
                .apply(customer);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `and` call:

```
isEmailValid().and(isPhoneNumberValid())
```

`this` refers to the object returned by `isEmailValid()`.

In the second `and` call:

```
isEmailValid().and(isPhoneNumberValid()).and(isAnAdult())
                                         ^^^
```

`this` refers to the object returned by the first `and` call. If that is not very clear, you can think of this as two steps:

```
CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailAndPhoneValid = 
    isEmailValid().and(isPhoneNumberValid());

// "this" refers to "isEmailAndPhoneValid"
isEmailAndPhoneValid.and(isAnAdult());
```

You should now see the pattern, that `this` refers to whatever is immediately before the `and`. The fact that it's in an lambda expression doesn't make much of a difference. It's the *method* that it is in, that matters.

What are the objects returned by `isEmailValid()` and `and` then? As you can see from the source code, both are declared to return an instance of a class that implements the interface `CustomerRegistrationValidator`, so those lambda expressions must evaluate to such objects. What is the class of those objects? Well, they are automatically generated, and have names like this:

```
combinatorpatttern.CustomerRegistrationValidator$$Lambda$4/0x0000000800067440@12f40c25
```

Hence the output when you print `this`.

Comment: Thanks, Sweeper great explanation I will mark this answered.